# Mime Type error from AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, css, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my django project to aws elastic branstalk. I followed all the steps. In EBS console, project health seems Ok. When I try to run the project, I get the following error.
**`Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.**

Here is my css and js addresses:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />`

`<script src="{%static 'js/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>`

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to go to your settings.py and do the following:

- Set DEBUG = False (the default installation comes with DEBUG = True)
- Add STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

Then you have to tell EB where your static files are gonna be. For that, create a file inside .ebextensions folder, at the root, named staticfiles.config (can be any name with .config extension). Write this inside:

```
container_commands:
  collectstatic:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
```

And that's it. I was very confused by the documentation, even the official tutorials are wrong. After a lot of research and tries, that's the solution that I came up to use.